# Finding Initial Parameter Values for Gompertz Model with Intercept

Tags: regression, self-study, modeling, nonlinear-regression

I have the following data:

```
y x
1275 230
1350 235
1650 250
2000 277
3750 522
4222 545
5018 625
6125 713
6200 735
8150 820
9975 992
12200 1322
12750 1900
13014 2022
13275 2155
```

I would like to find reasonable initial values for the model

$$y=\alpha+\beta_1\text{exp}(-\beta_2 e^{-\beta_3 x})+\epsilon$$

**What I know:**

For the Gompertz model, the inflection point satisfies

$$x=\frac{\text{log}(\beta_2)}{\beta_3}$$

For the Gompertz model we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \beta_1\text{exp}(-\beta_2 e^{-\beta_3 x})=\beta_1$$

so presumably with an intercept we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \alpha+\beta_1\text{exp}(-\beta_2 e^{-\beta_3 x})=\alpha+\beta_1$$

so we can set $\alpha+\beta_1=13275$, the maximum value of $y$ in the dataset.

However, I can't seem to combine what I know to find initial values.

**I would like to find reasonable initial values and not rely on specifying an exhaustive grid of values.**

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function) that the halfway point is found to be

$${\displaystyle x_{\text{hwp}}=-{\frac {\ln\left(\frac{ln(2)}{\beta_2}\right)}{\beta_3}}}$$

I let $x_{\text{hwp}}=713$, the median of the $x$'s.

As previously stated, I have $$x=\frac{\text{log}(\beta_2)}{\beta_3}$$

I let $x=1000$, since a plot of the data shows that a possible inflection point is around there.

By software, this system of equation results in $\beta_2=0.279$ and $\beta_3=-0.0013$.

I (randomly) decided to let $\alpha=13275$ and $\beta_1=-13275$, where $13275$ is the maximum value of $y$.

The model then converges after 15 iterations to

$$\hat{y}=12934.4-14349.2\cdot\text{exp}(-0.1214e^{0.00257x})$$

which are reasonably close to my initial estimates. I'm not sure why it would make sense to have $\hat{\alpha}=13275$ and $\hat{\beta_1}=-13275$ though.

Comment: I used the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameter estimates and an equation search found several sigmoidal equations the fit the posted data well, but I could not find a good fit to the equation you posted. If it might be of use I can post the top few results of the equation search. If you can use Python I can post source code for a graphical fitter for these equations.

Comment: Graphing the data, it appears that the pattern is logarithmic, rather than S-shaped. So, I don't think it's a problem if it doesn't fit the data well. I'm only looking to run this specific model though.

Comment: I think that the resulting values of $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ don't look as expected is because many of us would initially expect that $\hat{\alpha}$ would be the value of the intercept.  But the intercept is $\alpha+\beta_1 \exp{(-\beta_2)}$.  The point is that you've found the correct maximum likelihood estimates.

Comment: this certainly fits the data but thought that for a Gompertz curve $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ are $\gt 0$ I guess it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Anyway there is a solution satisfying the usual positivity constraints. It is 1403.91  11799.4 9.83262  0.00340595 with a sum of squares of 854256. which is higher than the solution which violates the constraints. After doing all this work I would appreciate knowing whether the constraints should be satisfied or not.

Comment: My textbook doesn't show those constraints but I see online that you are correct. I would be interested in seeing your approach with those constraints in mind.

Comment: well you don't HAVE to impose the constraint, but  then you are using a completely different family of curves. the two families are separated by the singular solution where $\beta_3=0$. To solve your problem you use the fact that the model is linear in y(x(1)) and y(x(n)) and use those values as independent parameters instead of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  I wrote all this up to discuss fitting a 4-5 parameter logistic but it seems to have disappeared

Comment: I found the post  if it is not clear I can say some more.   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62995/how-to-choose-initial-values-for-nonlinear-least-squares-fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical situation in nonlinear statistical modeling  is that the at least some of the parameters of interest to the modeler are not good parameters to use for parameterizing the model. I have found that is really difficult to convince a lot of people that they should 
parameterize their model in terms of parameters in which they have no interest.  Well duh!  It often turns out to be a good idea, however, because these new parameters lead to an easier and more stable estimation scheme. Once these uninteresting parameters have been estimated the parameters of interest can be calculated from them.   This is how it goes.

step1:
rescale the problem so that $x(15)=1$ and $y(15)=1$  this is just standard good advice for any model when it is possible.

step2: replace the independent variables $\alpha$ and $\beta_1$ with new independent variables  $y_1$ and $y_n$. Note that these are parameters and not observations. They are the predicted observed $y$ values for $x(1)$ and $x(15)$. However we have very good initial estimates for them namely the observed values
$y(1)$ and $y(n)$ for the values $x(1)$ and $x(n)$.
 Now since you have rescaled the $y$'s a good initial value for $y_n$ is 1.0 for $y_1$ it is 0.096045.  You can use almost any reasonable starting values for $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$, but they both should be $>0$, say $\beta_2=0.1$, $\beta_3=0.1$ It is not at all sensitive to these initial values. The initial values $\beta_2=10$, $\beta_3=10$ converge to the same solution.

step 3: Solve the linear system

\begin{align}
y_1&=\alpha+\beta_1\text{exp}(-\beta_2 e^{-\beta_3 x(1)}) \\
y_n&=\alpha+\beta_1\text{exp}(-\beta_2 e^{-\beta_3 }) \\
\end{align}

for $\alpha$ and $\beta_1$ in terms of $y_1,y_n,\beta_2,$ and $\beta_3$
This is just a little bit of matrix algebra.
In any system which supports matrix algebra. You form the matrix
$M$
$$
  M=    \begin{bmatrix}
          1&\exp(-\beta_2 e^{-\beta_3 x(1)})  \\
            1&\exp(-\beta_2 e^{-\beta_3})\ \ \\
       \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then 
$$  \begin{bmatrix}
       \alpha  \\
       \beta_1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}   =  M^{-1}   
      \begin{bmatrix}
       y_1  \\
       y_n  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now the minimization is carried out in two phases. For the first phase
$\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ are estimated for the fixed values of  $y_1$ and $y_n$. In the second phase all four parameters are estimated.
Hereis the fitted data plot.
[image: gompertz model fit]

The estimates for the original parameters are
1403.9062  11799.399 9.8326183  0.0034059501
Notice that at no time did one need to look at any aspect of the data. The only assumption involved is that a Gompertz curve should be used. Everything else is automatic.  This same procedure works for many kinds of growth curves.
I used AD Model Builder to fit the model, but it can easily be done in R
(so it must be simple).

Comment: @whuber  I wonder if I have posted solutions to enough  of these kinds of problems to convince you that the method is general?

Comment: Effectively you fix the parameters $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ turning it into a linear regression to make an initial guess of $\alpha$ and $\beta_1$ (where you choose to use the end points where the effect of $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ is smaller). The rescaling seems superfluous to me, and I wonder how much more useful this method is than just taking $\alpha =y(1)$ and $\beta_1 = y(15)-y(1)$.

Comment: Well don't just wonder about it.  If the data are really informative any parameterization will probably work. What you should do is to generate data with variable amounts of noise and fewer points near the tails so that there is less information about the asymptotes and compare the performance.

Comment: the question was rhetoric.

Comment: OK sorry we wasted my time.

Comment: On the other hand your question may be rhetoric (sic) but everything you said is also wrong. If I don't respond people might mistakenly think you have a point